# What capacity is ethereum using recently?

Tags: transactions, clients, blocks

What capacity is ethereum using recently? 
How many more people can use ethereum now?

What is current blocksize, and what are all the data being broadcasted between nodes?

I read that ethereum just server only for logical components of various contracts. Where are other data currently?

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum SE, please consider asking one question per thread in the future.

Comment: It is stil a single question. You need to understand that I am asking about actual capacity/potencial capacity of ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone can answer how many people are using Ethereum right now. You can [monitor the network here](https://stats.ethdev.com/).

There is [no hardcoded block size limit](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/comment/7371/#Comment_7371) in Ethereum. However, the number of contract calls and standard transactions is limited by the gas limit, which is 1.2x of the exponential moving average. So there's only so much gas that can be expended per block, even though it can grow, of course.

The current gas limit per block is at around 3 million. Note that each call to the contract to the caller cost an amount of Ether defined by `(gas sent to contract)*(price of gas as defined by caller)` so sending 10 thousend transactions per block could end up quite a pricey endeavour.